# Is it possible for Bootstrap navbar to work the same way as bootstrap tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By this I mean, is it possible to loads the different links dynamically, like you would with the tabs? I don't want any loading to take place, just for the content to show immediately.

Exactly like in the Bootstrap Tabs documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Is this possible?

Comment: I currently have the nav-tabs working. http://jsfiddle.net/gubhe20n/ But I prefer the actual .navbar styling

Comment: copy the navbar styling to the nav-tabs

Comment: You could achieve this using hide() and show() with jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the Bootstrap navbar styles:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

instead of:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
```

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gubhe20n/1/).